# Sending Text from Django Server to Android

Tags: android, django

I'm building an Android app which takes a photo, saves it as a jpg file and sends it to a server that saves it in its directory. Though I successfully wrote the code on Android/Django which the app sends the image (using Http POST and MultiPartEntity) and the back-end server saves it, I'm wondering how I can have the server, in turn, reply to the app with a simple text response and the mobile app to retrieve it. Thanks!

Comment: Why not just return the data you need from the view handling the upload?

Comment: @bitgarden: I was actually thinking of processing the image and then sending a response depending on the result...

Comment: so what exactly is the problem? you just send the post request which returns some data.